# How to perform text search together with geoNear?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I am programing a Mongo query builder and I found two statements in documentation:

> (Text search) The $match stage that includes a $text must be the first stage in the pipeline.
>
> (Geo search) You can only use $geoNear as the first stage of a pipeline.

Which basically means the same, so... how to use those together?

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I've recently had a similar problem so I thought I'd post my solution.

In my case I wanted:

- first to use full-text search on user-supplied keywords as a filter
- then, sort the results by distance from user-supplied coordinates
- user could choose to provide keywords, location or both (the difficult case)

I tackled it with a block of code like this:

```
let query = {}

if(req.query.keywords){
  if(req.query.lng || req.query.lat){
    db.collection("service")
      .find({ $text: { $search: req.query.keywords }})
      .toArray()
      .then(docs => query._id = { $in: docs.map(doc => doc._id) })
  } else {
    query.$text = { $search: req.query.keywords }
  }
}

if(req.query.lat && req.query.lng){
  query.location = {
    $nearSphere: {
      $geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [req.query.lng, req.query.lat]
      }
    }
  }
}

db.collection("service").find(query)
```

Basically if a text search or a geo search is desired by itself, the appropriate query is built no problem. If both are needed, it does a text query first, and then passes the returned document ids as a filter to the second.

This is the most performant solution I could find!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can. One thing I've done in the past is perform both queries and merge the results in the application code.

Comment: mongodb forever holding Ls.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [$match aggregation stage](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and use [$geoWithin](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/geoWithin/#mongodb-query-op.-geoWithin) (or [$geoIntersect](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/geoIntersects/)) along with [$text](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/text-search-in-aggregation/) operator. That seems to be the best solution.

MongoDB Atlas Search also allows filtering for full-text and location at the same time.